# Appium: How to start the appium using command line

Tags: server, appium

I want to run same script on multiple devices and for that i need to start multiple appium server instances.
I have been searching some **"node. -p 4327 -U 23EDF343"** kind of command to start the Appium server instance but could not get it to start.

Can somebody help me here to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

To start appium on multiple ports, just open the terminal as many ports you want to start. Then use this:

```
appium -p 4722 -bp 5422
```

Make sure to use different port and bootstrap on each terminal.